# java thread and datagram socket receiving

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am new to both datagram sockets and threading. When I run the code in my command prompt I was expecting to see both 6500 and 6501 printing out but only saw 6500. Why is the code not running the second start()? How can I thread multiple receiving datagram sockets (easiest way, not necessarily best way)?

```
public class startThread {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {
    new routerInterface(6500, "receive").start();
    new routerInterface(6501, "receive").start();
}
}

public routerInterface(int virPort, String action) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(virPort);
    if (action.compareTo("receive")==0){
        request = new DatagramSocket(clientPort);
        receive();
    }
}

public static void receive() throws Exception{
      while(true) { 
          System.out.println("We are recieving here");
          DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(udpPack, udpPack.length);  
          request.receive(p);
          byte[] reciv = p.getData();
      }
}
```

Comment: this code is syntactically incorrect and makes no sense.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky well maybe next time you can explain why it is syntactically incorrect and makes no sense rather than simply saying that. This is the first time writing a thread and I did not know I needed the run() method.

Comment: did you run this sample code through a java compiler?  Because I don't see how this could compile.

Comment: There is a lot more to the code than what I posted. I just put what I thought was relevant. But yes it compiled fine (but I did not have run in my code which was the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `receive()` from the `run()` method, not from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that threading needed the method run().

Comment: @KevinMoore Then I suggest you have a good look at the Javadoc for Thread and Runnable, and maybe the relevant part of the Java Tutorial as well.

Comment: Yeah I should go through the Javadoc more. I was using a tutorial to get as far as I did and I ignored the run aspect thinking it was just a random name the example used and not a necessity. I am rushing to much. I do agree with you though I should read up more before asking a basic question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you receive in constructor rather than run method. So first one is blocking. Second never starts.